# Python Selectionsort, can't use len()

Tags: python, sorting, built-in

```
def selectionSort(list1):
   for sixNumbers in range(len(list1) - 1, 0, -1):
       maxPos = 0
       for position in range(1, sixNumbers + 1):
           if list1[position] > list1[maxPos]:
               maxPos = position

       value = list1[sixNumbers]
       list1[sixNumbers] = list1[maxPos]
       list1[maxPos] = value

def main():
    list1 = [45, 7, 5, 24, 12, 1]
    selectionSort(list1)
    print(list1)

main()
```

How do I not use the `len()`? My instructor told me not to use the built-in sort function. Any suggestion? Also, do not give me the code, give me some tips, so I can try to rewrite it.

Comment: `len()` is not built-in `sort()` function. Are you not allowed to use any built-in functions?

Comment: `sixNumbers` is a really bad name for a single number.

Comment: @ErikAllik I renamed it to i

Comment: @RohitJain I think I might have misheard him. "You may not use any built-in Python sort functions." So am I fine with the len()?

Comment: @Singh2013 - Well, yes, if that is what he said.  `len` doesn't sort at all.

Comment: @iCodez Alright Thanks. I might have misheard him. Thanks guys!

Comment: also swapping the values is much easier than that in python. `list1[six_number], list1[maxPos] = list1[maxPos], list1[six_number]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really dumb way of counting elements without using len() is to loop though the values using a for loop. Increment every time though the loop to get the count.